# Logging in Netlogo web

Tags: logging, netlogo

Is there a way to log or record data on NetLogo Web?

The NetLogo docs mention a way to [log data using log4j](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/logging.html#starting-logging), but I cannot find any reference to whether this can be done on a browser through NetLogo web.

Comment: you seem to be striking out here — you might try asking on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/netlogo-devel

Comment: Turns out, it does have a [logging extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Tortoise/wiki/Experimental:-Logging-Extension)
 (although experimental).

Comment: Nice!! You should answer your own question (Stack Overflow allows that).